# Mobile Report Publisher Blank page on preview with parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssas

So, I'm trying to make a mobile report with parameters in Mobile Report Publisher.

My dataset is so big and i want to load in my repport only specific items by default.

I define my parameters in my dataset. I find my parameters in the report editor. But when i bind one parameter with one of my selected item, i got a problem. My selection list does not care about my parameter. When i enter in preview mode, i get a blank page.

For information, i foloow the MS tutorial :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/mobile-reports/add-parameters-to-a-mobile-report-reporting-services

Even if i write default values in my report's parameters, it do not care about them.

[IMG : My parameters binded with my selection lists and my parameters in my DS and my blank page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3GLb.png)

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

We've had to set our dataset parameters to allow nulls and then the sprocs deal with those else it caused problems in the mobile designer